# Boss never talks with me

Tags: professionalism

My boss talks all the project related things to my colleague. He ignores me. What should I do in this case? He asks only project updates and what am I doing.

Actually, the colleague is not my senior, so why boss discusses all things related to project with him and not with me?

Am I lacking something? Should I talk this out with him[Boss]?

EDIT:

There are no differences regarding education but my colleague is hired before me.

Comment: Was your colleague hired before you? Are there any differences in education and experience between him and you? If for any of these questions your answer is positive, you may want to edit your question re: seniority.

Comment: Have you noticed that at university lectures or elsewhere the lecturer has eye contact mostly with 2-3 people, who show more interest and attention? If you college has no obvious advantage (like education, experience, etc.), your situation is likely to be very similar. Try to show more interest and enthusiasm.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does this affect your job/performance or are you just jealous?

Comment: Your question has been closed because you are not really asking a practical question.  Perhaps the question should be how do I engage my boss more on the project?  What is it you are wanting to know.  What should I do in this situation is just too broad, and it is not our decision to make.  We can help you achieve your goal but you need to decide what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long have you worked for him?

Your boss may be a shy person, uncomfortable talking to new people.  I've worked for people like that.  Not everyone in management is as outgoing as they should be.  When I was younger I thought it was me, but later I realized that my manager was just as shy as me.  I suggest you talk to some other people in your office who have known him longer and see what they think.